# Using autoReleased objects without an NSAutoReleasePool?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos

I'm writing my very first steps in Objective-C.
I followed some examples and the official documentation, and am using autoreleased objects* without explicitly declaring an NSAutoReleasePool.

* By autoreleased objects I mean: `SomeClass *obj = [SomeClass someClass];`

Is it ok to do it this way?
Will it cause a memory problem?
Is declaring a NSAutoReleasePool more efficient?

edit: I made a mistake in the code example, what I meant was getting an object by it's class factory method instead of `alloc`ing an instance of it. This factory methods [often|always] return autoreleased objects, right? for example: `[NSString stringWithCString:x]`

Comment: Beware of texts (including many, many posts on Stack Overflow) that say that some methods return autoreleased objects. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don’t. It’s more accurate and productive to think of them as methods that return objects that are not owned by the caller.

Comment: Right. So, using them within the calling scope is safe, and beyond that, it should be `retain`ed, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to create an autorelease pool explicitly usually. When you do normal Mac programming using the AppKit framework, there will be an implicit autorelease pool which is handled by the event loop. You need to concern yourself with autorelease pools mainly on two occasions:

- Your code runs in a background thread: If you have a background thread there is no autorelease pool created for you and you will have to do this manually.
- You have a tight loop where you create and destroy a lot of objects. If in this loop any objects are autoreleased they will not actually be released until the autorelease pool is drained. This means that your memory consumption will rise, even though you don't reference those objects anymore. In this situation having a local autorelease pool can help with performance, although switching from autoreleasing to explicit retain/release is probably more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean literally Class, but someClass, will correct it.

Comment: It's the application object that creates and drains the autorelease pool with each event, not the run loop. If you only create a run loop, not an application object, you will still need to create and drain your own pool.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question: that's a no-no. You will leak memory if you autorelease an object (or use an autoreleased object) in a scope that has no autorelease pool.

#### perhaps ignore the following:

With regard to your example, it might be rather confusing the way you've written it, since `Class` is a typedef of `struct objc_class*`. So, you're really declaring a pointer-to-a-pointer to a class, and then assigning a pointer to a class to it. Which won't work. Moreover, since `Class` is not an Objective-C “class-type” per se, you can't send messages to it.
But all this is neither here nor there, since `±class` does not return an autoreleased object.

Comment: I would suspect that Petruza is working on the main thread in a normal Cocoa app, so there is automatically an autorelease pool in place and it is **perfectly ok to not explicitly create an autorelease pool**. It is only necessary to deal with autorelease pools on secondary threads and in situations where optimization is needed (see the answer by frenetisch applaudierend below). The `Class *obj = [Class class];` code still doesn't make sense though, as you have explained.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean literally `Class`, but `someClass`, will correct it.

Comment: @puzzle Yep, you're absolutely right. In most situations you'll encounter, there will definitely be an active autorelease pool. But you won't have one automatically in `main`, `+load`, etc.